# How can I open the files only in a specific window in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I have configured my emacs as follows, and I would like to open and operate the source files only in the first window(*scratch*).

But the *sr-speedbar* loves to open the new file in the lastest window(e.g. the newly open *shell* window).

How can I stop it from opening files in some unwanted windows?

[image]

Comment: **(A)** You can set a certain window as dedicated so that the display-buffer family of functions avoids it -- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html  **(B)** You can adjust the display-buffer-alist to your liking -- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html and http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html  **(C)** You can adjust the source code of speedbar to your liking.

Comment: I have tried **(A)**, and I set the \*shell* window as a dedication, but sr-speedbar insists in opening the file by spliting the last window(i.e. \*shell*), and ignoring the scratch window.

Comment: A cursory word-search of the `sr-speedbar.el` library for the term `split-window` pulls up two results: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sr-speedbar.el I personally like option **(C)** -- modify the source and make it do what you want. Instead of `split-window`..., perhaps you want to use `display-buffer` to select an **existing** window? . . . (modifying the code as needed to accommodate that new revision).

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem as well. My solution, which I can personally recommend, is to use the [purpose](https://github.com/bmag/emacs-purpose) package.

It allows you to dedicate specific windows to specific "purposes" which each have user-configurable associated modes; for instance, the `edit` purpose might have `prog-mode` associated with it, the `view` purpose might have `info-mode associated with it, etc. Any time a new buffer is to be opened, if there is a window currently dedicated to that purpose, Emacs will force said buffer to be opened in that dedicated window.

As an example, my default Emacs "workspace" consists of one large `edit` window, one `comm` window for IRC, and two `admin` windows -- one for RSS and another for email.

Highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

To open only in single windows do customize the emacs initialization file (in Ubuntu (18.04.01) it in (~/.emacs ) and add the

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)       ;; Don't show initial Emacs-logo and info
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for though I did not know what it was called.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is set the buffers that I do not want to change to sticky-buffer-mode. (Just do M-x sticky-buffer-mode when you have the buffer selected). Use this command to toggle the mode. A sticky buffer will not change, so if you make your shell sticky you should get what you want.